# I am trying to split two variables but for some reason it is returning 0 instead of the intended result

Tags: c

I was testing this program and it was giving the wrong results, after several tries I decided to "split the equation into pieces" and return what each "piece". When I did that I saw that the error was that when I do "x/y" the program shows 0 and it shouldn't show that. For example for an x=120, y=181 and z=1 the result should be 956.4 and the variables should be var = 2.525(this is right in the program), var1 = 0.663(this is the wrong one) and then fine=956.40. In other words, the problem is in the var1 variable, but I have tried many different ways and it keeps going wrong. Any tip?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


double coima(int x, int y, int z)
{
    double var2;
    double var1;
    double var;
    double coima;
    double km_passados = y - x;
if ((z = 0))
{
     if ( (km_passados <= 0))
     {
        coima = 0;
     }
     else if ((km_passados<=20))
     {
            var = 1 + (0.25*(y-x)/10);
            var1 = x/y;
            var2 = var1 + var;
            coima = var2 * 60;
     }
     else if((km_passados > 20 && km_passados <= 40))
     {
            var = 1 + (0.25*(y-x)/10);
            var1 = x/y;
            var2 = var1 + var;
            coima = var2 * 120;
     }
     else if((km_passados > 40 && km_passados <= 60))
     {
            var = 1 + (0.25*(y-x)/10);
            var1 = x/y;
            var2 = var1 + var;
            coima = var2 * 300;
     }
     else if ((km_passados > 60))
     {
            var = 1 + (0.25*(y-x)/10);
            var1 = x/y;
            var2 = var1 + var;
            coima = var2 * 500;
     }
     return coima;
}
else if ((z = 1))
{
    if ((km_passados <= 30))
    {
            var = 1 + (0.25*(y-x)/10);
            var1 = x/y;
            var2 = var1 + var;
            coima = var2 * 60;
    }
    if ((km_passados >30 && km_passados <=60))
        {
            var = 1 + (0.25*(y-x)/10);
            var1 = x/y;
            var2 = var1 + var;
            coima = var2 * 120;
        }
        if ((km_passados > 60 && km_passados <= 80))
        {
            var = 1 + (0.25*(y-x)/10);
            var1 = x/y;
            var2 = var1 + var;
            coima = var2 * 300;
        }
        if ((km_passados > 80))
        {
            var = 1 + (0.25*(y-x)/10);
            var1 = x/y;
            var2 = var1 + var;
            coima = var2 * 500;
        }
        return var1;
}
}

double test_coima()
{
    int x; //velocidade permitida
    int y; //velocidade atingida
    int z; //dentro ou fora da localidade
    while (scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &y, &z) !=EOF)
    {
        double z = coima(x,y,z);
        printf("%lf\n", z);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    test_coima();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beware of integer division with `x/y`.  Since both operands are `int`s, the result will also be an `int`, truncating any extra decimal part.  e.g. `120 / 181 == 0`.  If you first cast one of the operands to a `double`, the result will be a `double` instead.

Comment: So you have added the extra parens in `((z = 0))` to silence the warning which was pointing to a nasty bug. Bad idea. Read the warnings and take them seriously

Comment: You should remove the double parans from all our `if` conditions. In best case they are useless, in worst case they hide errors as with your erronous assignmenta.

Answer (score 1):

`if ((z = 0))` is very suspicious.

That statement will ***assign*** `0` to `z`, and then skip the entire if-statement.

---

I think what you want is:
`if ((z == 0))`

That will ***compare*** `z` to `0`, and execute the if-statement if `z` is `0`

In C language `==` (double-equal) is used for Comparison.
  Single-equal (`=`) is used for Assignment.

Similar for: `else if ((z = 1))`
(that is again, an assignment, not a comparison test)